# Read output from subprocess cli, yowsup-cli to store the output

Tags: python, subprocess, yowsup

I have made the following subprocess to interact with the `yowsup-cli`.

```
connection_string = "python /root/yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --yowsup --config config.json"
popen_parameters = connection_string.split(" ")
proc = Popen(popen_parameters, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

out, err = proc.communicate()
```

The interaction works fine I am able to send parameters but I have no return from the CLI of the yowsup-cli. the return is working in the background. 
I need to send some variables from the input and receive the result from `yowsup-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

I used Pexpect and create a algorithm to reach my goal.
For those who will need to create an automation here is what I used:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')
fout = open('mylog.txt','wb')
child.logfile = fout

child.sendline('/usr/bin/python /root/yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --yowsup --config config.json')
child.expect('offline')
```

The trick was to create a `bash` child process before running python script.

After the last line the `child.expect('offline')` you can send the desired commands in a logic that will fit your porpoise.

Hope this help others